# Lost header information when httpwebrequest timeout

Tags: c#, cookies, timeout, httpwebrequest

I am writing code to surf a website using spring webflow.

I have to update my cookie with his set-cookie header every request else my session will be terminated.

Sometime a request could bump into webException so I need to catch the webException response headers for the cookie update so my next request is still valid

The problem happens with timeout exception, other exceptions like 503 works fine. The webRespones is always null but I can see the server had respond the header part and only stuck in sending the body part in fiddler. My session will be terminated without catching the header response properly. Is there any work around for this?

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
    webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookieCollection);
    webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
    webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000;
    using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        //A function handling the cookie adding
        AddCookies(webResponse.Headers, cookieCollection, webResponse.ResponseUri.Host);
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    HttpWebResponse webResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    if (webResponse == null) throw ex;
    //Null webResponse when timeout, the received header information is dropped.
    AddCookies(webResponse.Headers, cookieCollection, webResponse.ResponseUri.Host);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to try `HttpClient` instead of `WebRequest`?

Comment: I will report once I tried after this busy weekend, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Have to tried to set AllowAutoRedirect to false? Redirections may happen undercovers.

Comment: Yes, I set AllowAutoRedirect to false and I am sure that request has no redirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout exception is implemented on the client side so the response will be null. You could use raw sockets to implement the get, but the easiest solution would probably be to increase the timeout value so you get the response.

Comment: I dont have the time to build a webrequest class from raw socket. Is there any existing solution or is it possible to change the httpwebrequest behaviour? It seems to be a lost packet that I can never receive the response. I had tried like 120s and still no response body

Comment: I believe that all http client libraries will have the same problem when a client side timeout is hit.  If you really don't care about the body then you could try to use HEAD requests but this will only work if the server correctly handles the head verb.